# Error details: Field `af` does not exist

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am getting this error for 2 days.
I have read any links regarding the same error and each time no effect.

I am trying simple inheritance
Here is my `employee.py` file

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'
    _description = "Inherited modules"

    af = fields.Char(string="AF")
```

Here is my `employee.xml` file

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="hr_employee_contact_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Contact">
                        <group>
                            <field name="af"/>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="employee_list_action">
            <field name="name">Contacts</field>
            <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>
        <menuitem id="configuration_menu" name="Configuration"
                  parent="main_ayda_project_menu"/>
        <menuitem id="contact_menu" name="Employee"
                  parent="configuration_menu"
                  action="employee_list_action"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Here is my `__openerp__.py` file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "Smart Gateway",

    'summary': """ Smart Gateway """,

    'description': """
        Long description of module's purpose
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    'category': 'Uncategorized',
    'version': '0.1',

    'depends': ['base',
                'hr'],

    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        # 'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
        'views/contact_master/contact.xml',
        'views/employee.xml'
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
}
```

And here is my `__init__.py` file

```
from . import controllers
from . import models
```

I have taken care of dependency also still getting this error.

```
ParseError: "Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `af` does not exist

Error context:
View `hr.employee`
[view_id: 1859, xml_id: n/a, model: hr.employee, parent_id: 352]
None" while parsing file:///C:/Odoo%209.0-20160127/server/openerp/addons/ayda_project/views/employee.xml:3, near
<record id="hr_employee_contact_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Contact">
                        <group>
                            <field name="af"/>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: i suspect you're not importing your modules correctly...show us the layout of your module and it's files, run `tree your_module`. we need that unless all answers are just guesses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your employee.py file into an __init__.py file in the same directory.
If it is in the same directory as your other .py files.

```
from . import controllers
from . import models
from . import employee
```

Update your addon

Comment: Problem resolved. It may be silly to ask but I have to learn so I am asking, that how do you know we have to import employee for this, why not hr. Because I have seen some old question having the same issue and there they used hr module.

Comment: The reason you have to import employee is because you made changes in your file employee.py. But odoo will not know about it until it reads your file. This is why it must be imported. If you do not import it your file is never even noticed by odoo which is why it did not know about the field you added. Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Comment: Got the explanation. Thank you phillip, marked it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add `from . import employee` to `__init__.py` inside `models` folder.

`models/__init__.py` file:

```
...
from . import employee
```

Comment: I have another issue regarding making own module. So should I ask it here or make a new thread. Because for that thing also, I couldn't find any useful resource.

Comment: @user3481574 I suggest you to make a new question.